# htaccess - What is rewrite rule for a wildcard string after the base?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

For instance, I want `www.example.com/mr.chase` to redirect to `www.exapmle.com/index.php?name=mr.chase`

Currently, I use a symbol (a period) so that it matches a symbol first before checking the rule.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^\.([^/]+)/?$   index.php?name=$1 [NC]
```

The above works. However, if I remove the `\.`, it will APPEAR to work (successfully redirects), but I receive values I do not expect.

I use PHP, and find that $_GET['name'] produces `index.php` instead of `mr.chase`.

I only have issues grabbing my GET variables when the base is a wildcard, and there is nothing else to match. Insight would be great! I apologize if I'm on the wrong track here.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?network=$1 [NC]` This is what I use to match the wildcard.

Comment: @Chase - if it works, put it as answer, you'll get more reputation.

Comment: I'm sorry. I should have clarified. My rule that I added above works to redirect, but I cannot successfully get the correct GET variable. Instead of "mr.chase", I get "index.php".

Comment: Very odd. `^([^\/]+)\/?$` works fine for "mr.chase" on http://www.regextester.com - But i've never even seen the filename show up in the $_GET variables in a .htaccess rewrite

Comment: @Mick It's boggling my mind right now as well. The same regular expression works on my other pages, as long as I match _something_ in it. For example, `^profile/([^/]+)/?$` will work just fine if the URL is `www.example.com/profile/mr.chase`.

Comment: I don't get it. How does prefixing the `\.` dot help? The `mr.chase` example does not start with a dot. And why don't you use an assertion or RewriteCond to exclude `index.php` from matching?

Comment: @mario index.php shouldn't even be in the match if the request is example.com/mr.chase - I do however agree that having `\.` there is odd.

Comment: @Mick: It can appear there if the RewriteRule is run twice. The `[L]` flag instead of the redundant `[NC]` might help.

Comment: @Mario: Was not aware of that, allways use [L] - But thanks, allways good to learn something new :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your example, and neither what the `\.` and not matching discussion was about. But to prevent `index.php` from showing up as parameter a simple assertion should do:

```
 RewriteRule ^(?!index.php)([\w.]+)/?$   index.php?name=$1  [L]
 #                 ^         ^
 #                 |         |
 #               exclude     |
 #                          only letters and dots
```

If that doesn't work it's an issue with your setup (FastCGI sometimes incurs additonal rewriting). Or another RewriteRule matches (= clear everything but above example, and the .htaccess files in upper directories). And for further debugging look into `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` and the other variables for details.

Set up the `RewriteLog` if you cannot find the cause with these tips.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of your ^ matching the begginning of the string. It's looking for a period as the first character. Remove the ^

Also, a better pattern may be this:

```
/(.*?\.?([^/]+))/?$
```

This will match 'mr.chase' instead of just '.chase'

Comment: I apologize for the confusing rule above. I used `RewriteRule ^\.([^/]+)/?$   index.php?name=$1 [NC]` as an alternative. This would still match `mr.chase`. However, I want to not have to match anything, whether it be a period or word, which I can do. The problem is it does not grab `mr.chase`, and instead grabs `index.php`. Essentially, the first string after `www.example.com/` is my query string, with nothing to match before it. I hope that is more clear.

Comment: So you request `www.example.com/mr.chase` and `$_GET['name']` is equal to `index.php` !?!? I hope I'm understanding this wrong still, cuz if that's right, then something very odd is going on indeed!

Comment: That is exactly what is going on. I'm not getting any redirect loop errors, but is it possible that because my regex matches ANYTHING that isn't a `/`, that it redirects to index.php?name=$1, and since that qualifies under my regex, it manages to redirect again and uses `index.php` instead of `mr.chase` as my $_GET var. I have no clue, but I'm trying to figure out how to exclude a string from the regex.

Comment: No, you're not using a redirect, this is just an internal rewrite, so it will only apply this rule once. Do you possibly have other rewrites in other locations that are causing a redirect in turn, causing this .htaccess to be triggered twice?